# Is SourceAddress relative to SourceProcess in MmCopyVirtualMemory?

Tags: c++, c, driver, kmdf

I try to use the following code from kernel mode in a driver:

```
NTSTATUS NTAPI MmCopyVirtualMemory
(
    PEPROCESS SourceProcess,
    PVOID SourceAddress,
    PEPROCESS TargetProcess,
    PVOID TargetAddress,
    SIZE_T BufferSize,
    KPROCESSOR_MODE PreviousMode,
    PSIZE_T ReturnSize
);
```

I use it in the following way:

```
PEPROCESS process;
NTSTATUS status;
unsigned int readValue;

// get notepad.exe process -> Notepad is opened already and this is the ID from Task Mgr
status = PsLookupProcessByProcessId((HANDLE)7252, &process);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "\n\n ## Lookup By Id failed. ##\n\n");
    if (status == STATUS_INVALID_CID)
    {
        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "\n\n ## Id could not be found. ##\n\n");
    }
    goto Exit;
}

SIZE_T cbBytesReturned;
status = MmCopyVirtualMemory(process, 0x00, PsGetCurrentProcess(), &readValue, sizeof(unsigned int), KernelMode, &cbBytesReturned);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "\n\n ## MemCopy failed. ##\n\n");
}
else
{
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "\n\n ## MemCopy DONE ##\n\n");
}

ObfDereferenceObject(process);
```

Currently this fails. I assumed that 0x00 points to the first byte of memory of the process I am reading from. A I wrong or is that relative which means process + 0x00 is the first memory location ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you think your code is going to work, your input values for MmCopyVirtualMemory are not correct.

1. You're passing a NULL pointer for the second parameter. How is the Windows Kernel supposed to know where the memory you'd like to copy from the SourceProcess is present if you don't give it a valid address?
2. You're passing the pointer address to a local variable as the fourth parameter, yet the fourth parameter is supposed to be a pointer address which is valid under the process you're targeting (the third parameter). The pointer address used for the fourth parameter is supposed to be where you'd like to put the memory copied from the SourceAddress (within the virtual memory of SourceProcess) within the TargetProcess.
3. For the fifth parameter, you're passing the size of an unsigned int? This is also incorrect.

I believe the fifth parameter (BufferSize) should be the length of how much memory you'd like to copy from SourceAddress into TargetAddress. If this is the case, make sure that there is enough room at TargetAddress - take this with a grain of salt.

I suggest you take a look at the function prototype which you shared in your original post and re-check your code, and try again, taking on-board my comments here and after some more research on the routine.

Remember though, MmCopyVirtualMemory is not officially documented and you'll be taking a risk by using it in any production-level source code. I recommend strongly that you re-consider your options if this isn't just an educational experiment, because stable and documented code is generally an important thing.